# Suddenly cannot open Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have been analyzing data with Matlab R2016a. But today when I was trying to analyze a data file of size 50MB, I failed to open Matlab, which stays at the initialization image but cannot enter the main interface. No error reported either. I restarted the machine but it still does not work.

Has anyone encountered this kind of issue? What might be the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Matlab?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a technical support forum. [The MathWorks is, though](https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is because the file is too large. One needs to launch Matlab first then switch to the directory under which the file is saved.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense